# ¿Cómo iterar en una lista para la formación de un dataframe?

Tags: python, lista, pandas

Me encuentro haciendo alguna que otra prueba con pandas, este es mi código:

```
centros= {
"codigo":[2222,1111,3333],
"nombre":["a","b","c"],
"resultados academicos":{
    "evau":[[222,333,444,555,666],[2222,3333,4444,5555,6666],[22,33,44,55,66]],
  }
}

df = pd.DataFrame({"CODIGO":centros["codigo"], "NOMBRE":centros["nombre"], "evau": centros["resultados academicos"]["evau"]})
print(df)
```

con este código conseguiría algo así:
[image: Captura1]

Ahora bien lo que yo quiero es iterar en la lista de evau para lograr algo como esto:
[image: Captura2]

Si alguien sabe algo estaría agradecido. Muchas gracias

Comment: En el título de tu pregunta, decís _problema con..._. ¿Cuál es el problema? Dale un título más específico a tu pregunta: lee [ask].

Comment: Eso es hacer un pivot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En  primer lugar la inicialización de tu dataframe no me parece la mas correcta, teniendo en cuenta que partes de un diccionario.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(centros)
```

Y tienes el df:

```
 codigo nombre           resultados academicos
0    2222      a       [222, 333, 444, 555, 666]
1    1111      b  [2222, 3333, 4444, 5555, 6666]
2    3333      c            [22, 33, 44, 55, 66]
```

luego puedes descomponer la lista de la columna df['resultados academicos']

```
df2 = df['resultados academicos'].apply(pd.Series)

  0     1     2     3     4
0   222   333   444   555   666
1  2222  3333  4444  5555  6666
2    22    33    44    55    66
```

Y Unir ambos df sin la colunmna que inicialmente tenias con listas anidada.

```
df3 = pd.concat([df.drop(columns = 'resultados academicos'), df2] , axis=1)

  codigo nombre     0     1     2     3     4
0    2222      a   222   333   444   555   666
1    1111      b  2222  3333  4444  5555  6666
2    3333      c    22    33    44    55    66
```

Solo faltaría renombrar las columnas como desees:

```
df3.rename(columns={0: '20xx-xx',
                   1: '20xx-xx',
                   2: '20xx-xx',
                   3: '20xx-xx',
                   4: '20xx-xx'},
          inplace=True, errors='raise')

   codigo nombre  20xx-xx  20xx-xx  20xx-xx  20xx-xx  20xx-xx
0    2222      a      222      333      444      555      666
1    1111      b     2222     3333     4444     5555     6666
2    3333      c       22       33       44       55       66
```

Comment: Hola P. C. muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero en el primer paso ya me salta un error diciendo "Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering."

Comment: retocando algunas cosas ha funcionado pero evau se encuentra dentro de resultados académicos.